# How can I remove anchor tags from the result of preg_match_all?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

By using the code below, I get a result something like this, but I want to remove a `href` tag. Since my records are stored in an array,

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Title</a>
```

A solution like

```
 preg_replace("/<a>(.+)<\/a>/", "$1", $title);
```

doesn't work and echoes "Array". I want to strip all `<a>` tags and make it echo only titles. How can I achieve it? I am not good at regular expressions, so I got stuck.

Code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $site = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/?_208&filter=1&page=10");
        preg_match_all('@<div class="rand"><a href="http://www.example.com/content/(.*?)/(.*?).html">(.*?)</a></div>@', $site, $title);
        preg_replace("/<a>(.+)<\/a>/", "$1", $title); 

        echo $title[2][$i] . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476

Comment: You can use `substr()`. Why not?